# Prove that the solutions of IVP are defined for all $t ≥ 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assume $U = \mathbb{R} × \mathbb{R}^n$ and that $|f(t,x)| ≤ g(|x|)$ for some continuous function $g \in 
C([0, \infty))$  satisfying

$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \dfrac {1}{g(r)}dr = \infty$.

Prove that the solutions of IVP $x' = f(x; t);  x(t_0) = x_0$ are defined for all  $t ≥ 0$.

Could someone give me a hint how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can observe that, for a solution $\varphi(\cdot)$ of $x' = f(t,x)$, one has $\lvert \varphi(t) \rvert' \le \lvert f(t, \varphi(t))\rvert \le g(\lvert \varphi(t) \rvert)$ for $t$ in its interval of existence (assuming, of course, that $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ denotes the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$).  So the problem boils down to showing that all solutions of the scalar differential inequality $r' \le g(r)$ are defined for all $t \ge 0$.  Can you prove that?

Comment: I think I can do it now. My idea is to divide $ |\phi(t)|′≤g(|\phi(t)|)$ and calculate the integral from $0$ to $t& and use the hypothesis of the question from its idea. What do you think about this?

Comment: Yes, it means that the time needed for the norm of a solution to "reach" infinity is infinity.

Comment: thank you so much!